# Datetime-local Value to display AM but no year/month/day

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to display AM when my website loads (mm-dd-yyyy --:-- AM) in a date time local input. But i'm having a hard time understanding the value attribute of datetime-local.

Comment: Show us what have you done so far so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

**You can also consider using something like date.js:**

```html
 <html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js"></script>

<script>
   (function ()
   {
      document.write(new Date().toString("hh:mm tt"));
   })();
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check

var date = new Date();
date = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');
```

Note: It will show the time (AM/PM)